# Rename a file before a file is moved using Powershell

Tags: powershell

The code works file if I comment out the rename line below but what I want to achieve is to rename the file and then move the file. The file just stays in the source and does not move or rename at all with this line in.

```
function RenameFile($location, $filename, $extension){
    $d = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%M%D"
    $old = $location + $filename + $extension
    $new = $filename + "_" + $extension
}

$folder = 'C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\FileSystemWatcher\Folder to Monitor'
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubDirectories = $false; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action{
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    RenameFile -location "C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\FileSystemWatcher\Folder to Monitor\" -filename "TEST" -extension .txt
    Move-Item "C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\FileSystemWatcher\Folder to Monitor\*.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\FileSystemWatcher\New 
Folder 1"
}

# Unregister-Event FileCreated
```

Comment: Are `$d`, `$old`, and `$new` global variables? It appears you set them and do nothing with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `RenameFile` function does is set variables that appear to be never used.

In order to actually rename a file, you should call `Rename-Item`:

```
function RenameFile($location, $filename, $extension){
    Rename-Item -Path "$($location)/$($filename)$($extension)" -NewName "$($location)/$($filename)_$($extension)"
}
```

(The `$()` are there to avoid expansion conflicts with `/` and `_`)

See: [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thank you, I have gone with using: Rename-Item -Path "C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\FileSystemWatcher\NewShare0\Test1.txt" -NewName = "TEST1.txt" how can I make it so that its renamed to TEST1DDMMYYHHMMSS ? with the DD representing Day/ MM = Month etc so that the rename is always unique.

Comment: Use the `$d` variable mentioned in your question. `-NewName` would be `$($location)/$($filename)$($d)$($extension)`